# javascript to select all checkbox in gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

i am searching for the javascript that performs select all - deselect all feature in asp.net gridview.

So if a header checkbox is selected all the item templates checkbox should be selected. if any item template checbox is deselcted, the header checkbox should also be deselected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#GridView1 input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
this.checked=!this.checked;});
```

Add this on 'select all' button click